# How to disable keep screen on without restarting activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm launching an Android `Activity` and used

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to keep the screen on.

Later on, I cleared the flag with

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But that didn't take effect immediately. *If I suspend the app and resume it, then it would work*.

So this is how i'm setting the flags and starting the activity. This is a cordova phonegap app. In a SipAudioCall listener onRinging event:

```
Activity activity = SIP.this.cordova.getActivity();
  if (activity instanceof MonmouthTelecom) {
    if (((MonmouthTelecom) activity).isActivityPaused()) {
      Intent notifIntent = new Intent(SIP.this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
             Class.forName(SIP.this.cordova.getActivity().getComponentName().getClassName()));
      notifIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      Log.i(LOG_TAG, "opening app...");

      // set window flags here b4 starting activity...
      ((MonmouthTelecom) activity).setWindowFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            SIP.this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().startActivity(notifIntent);
      }
}
```

On the onCallEstablished event handler i call:

```
  ((MonmouthTelecom) activity).clearWindowFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

set and clear window flags is just:
(in defining the activity)

```
public void setWindowFlags(int flags) {
this.getWindow().addFlags(flags);
}
public void clearWindowFlags(int flags) {
this.getWindow().clearFlags(flags);
}
```

Comment: well that depends where u used the `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` statement

Comment: where should it go then? I start the activity with that flag and others when a call comes in. Once the call is established, theres no longer a need for it and call clearFlags

Comment: can u clear it a bit.. Is the call part of your application...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured this out. Apparently I was manipulating the views in different threads and with the cordova setup, the exception was not being outputted.

Calling the add/clear Flags in a runnable under `SIP.this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...});`
got it to work.